# Downloading ACS data for state legislative districts using tidycensus::get_acs()

Tags: r, census, tidycensus

I'm trying to download 5-year ACS data for state legislative districts (both upper and lower). According to documentation for the get_acs() command, state legislative districts are a supported geography (see [here](https://walker-data.com/tidycensus/articles/basic-usage.html#geography-in-tidycensus)).

However, when I try to download data using the command, I get the following error message:

> Error: Your API call has errors.  The API message returned is error: unknown/unsupported geography heirarchy.

Here's a minimum working example that produces the above message:

```r
tidycensus::get_acs(geography = "state legislative district (lower chamber)",
                    variables = "B05002_013E", year = 2014)
```

Any idea what's going on or how I can access ACS data for state legislative districts?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer on another site. Sharing in case anyone else is experiencing the same problem:

"From the documentation it looks like you need to supply a state to get_acs() for state legislative districts, so something like the following works for me:

`test <- get_acs(geography = "state legislative district (lower chamber)", variables = "B05002_013E", year = 2014, state = "NY")`
"